# Text and entry width not the same tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm starting to learn Tkinter library and I have a problem...
I use grid to set my window the way I want but I can't figure out how I can set the width of the entry widget the same as the text widget.
When I put the same number, I don't have the same width anyway...

Here is my code :

```
    from tkinter import *

def click():
    try:
        output.delete(0.0,END)
        entered_text=entry.get()
        output.insert(END, entered_text)
    except:
        output.insert(END, "")

def reset():
    output.delete(0.0,END)
    entry.delete(0,END)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = Tk()
    window.title("TEST")
    window.geometry("500x500")

    Label (window, text="Nombre de palettes :").grid(row=0,  sticky=W)
    Label (window, text="Prix :").grid(row=1, sticky=W)

    entry = Entry (window)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=2)

    output = Text(window, width=8, heigh=1,  wrap=WORD)
    output.grid(row=1, column=2)

    accepter=Button(window, text="Accepter",  width=6, command=click)
    accepter.grid(row=2, column=0)
    restart = Button(window, text="Reset", width=6,command=reset)
    restart.grid(row=2, column=1)
    fin = Button(window, text="Quitter", width=6,command=window.destroy)
    fin.grid(row=2, column=2)


    window.grid_columnconfigure(4, minsize=100)
    window.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to expand the widgets to fill the cell:

```
entry = Entry(window)
entry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E+W, padx=10)

output = Text(window, width=8, heigh=1,  wrap=WORD)
output.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E+W, padx=10)
```

Where `sticky=E+W` fills the cell horizontally, and then I add some padding `padx=10` to get a distance from the cell limits.

If one of the widgets always is bigger you can let that widget determine the cell width and then just expand the other widget.